# How change List<Unit> type to proper one in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have an issue with getting only information with passed coinList values. To begin with, I want to make coinList to `List<Coin>` instead of `List<Unit>` and I am out of ideas on how to change it. I want to compare `it.id` to the `coinList` if it has the same values then pass it to the function coin. Thank you in advance!

```
class GetCoinsUseCase @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: CoinRepository
){
    private val coinList = listOf("btc-bitcoin", "usdt-tether", "eth-ethereum")

     operator fun invoke(): Flow<Resource<List<Coin>>> = flow{
        try{
            emit(Resource.Loading<List<Coin>>())
            val coins = repository.getCoins().map { if (it.id.equals(coinList)){ it.toCoin() }}
            emit(Resource.Success<List<Coin>>(coins))
        }catch (e: HttpException){
            emit(Resource.Error<List<Coin>>(e.localizedMessage ?: "Error occurred"))
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe something like this would work, first doing a filter to only retrieve relevant items, then mapping

```
    val coinsList = arrayListOf<String>("foo", "bar")
    val coins = repository.getCoins().filter { it.id in coinsList }.map {
        it.toCoin()
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but i get an error in `{ it in coinList }` Type mismatch - Required: Boolean
Found: Unit

Comment: so what does `repository.getCoins()` return, because this seems to work for me

Comment: its suspend function of my interface Repository

Comment: I think it might need to be `{ it.id in coinList }`

Comment: ahh yeah sorry, when i was running this locally i was using strings, not objects